# Regarding using directives and performance

Tags: c#, performance

I have a C# code file which has few `using` directives. Out of these, the classes from some of these are never used. Would it affect performance if those `using` directives are left in the code?

In the example shown below, the classes from `System.Linq` are never used, would it hurt performance if I leave it there in the code, especially in the case where there are many such files?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at the generated IL code. If it differs, then it may affect performance, if not ... well, no

Comment: "*would it hit performance*" - The answer is no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***There aren't any performance benefits, if that's what you mean.***

All references in an assembly are fully qualified; the compiler merely uses the references you provide in your code to fully qualify identifiers, so the only impact of unused references in your source code is a slight decrease in readability (why is this reference here?), and a trivial increase in compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.

At worst, *referenced assemblies* are not immediately loaded - they are loaded on the fly as needed. In the case they are not needed at all, then they are never loaded and omitted completely. Having an unused `using` directive laying around, is neither using a *referenced assembly*, or loading them, and optimised out when compiled (for lack of better words), in reality the `using` never existed... insert *eerie music*.

Comment: _"and optimised out when compiled"_ -- this answer implies that a `using` directive has some material effect after compilation when they _do_ have an effect. That's simply false. They aren't "optimized out". They simply don't even exist after compilation, whether or not they were needed for the code.

Comment: @PeterDuniho i can see why you would say that, probably a bad choice of words